# Converting Numbers to Excel Letter Column vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, chr

I am trying to write data to excel files using vb.net. So I my function which converts number column into excel letter columns.

```
Public Function ConvertToLetter(ByRef iCol As Integer) As String

    Dim Reminder_Part As Integer = iCol Mod 26
    Dim Integer_Part As Integer = Int(iCol / 26)

    If Integer_Part = 0 Then
        ConvertToLetter = Chr(Reminder_Part + 64)
    ElseIf Integer_Part > 0 And Reminder_Part <> 0 Then
        ConvertToLetter = Chr(Integer_Part + 64) + Chr(Reminder_Part + 64)
    ElseIf Integer_Part > 0 And Reminder_Part = 0 Then
        ConvertToLetter = Chr(Integer_Part * 26 + 64)
    End If


End Function
```

The Function works ok with any other numbers.

For example,

- 1 => A
- 2 => B
- ...
- 26 => Z
- 27 => AA
- ...
- 51 => AY
- 52 => t  (And here is when it start to went wrong) It is suppose to return AZ, but it returned t.

I couldn't figure out what part I made a mistake. Can someone help me or show me how to code a proper function of converting numbers to excel letter columns using vb.net.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should do what you want.

```
Private Function GetExcelColumnName(columnNumber As Integer) As String
    Dim dividend As Integer = columnNumber
    Dim columnName As String = String.Empty
    Dim modulo As Integer

    While dividend > 0
       modulo = (dividend - 1) Mod 26
       columnName = Convert.ToChar(65 + modulo).ToString() & columnName
       dividend = CInt((dividend - modulo) / 26)
   End While

   Return columnName
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple flaws in the logic, the second else clause is not required and the operations should be zero based.

```
Public Function ConvertToLetter(ByRef iCol As Integer) As String
    Dim col As Integer = iCol - 1
    Dim Reminder_Part As Integer = col Mod 26
    Dim Integer_Part As Integer = Int(col / 26)

    If Integer_Part = 0 Then
        ConvertToLetter = Chr(Reminder_Part + 65)
    Else
        ConvertToLetter = Chr(Integer_Part + 64) + Chr(Reminder_Part + 65)
    End If


End Function
```

Comment: Thank you. The code you provide does not work for 26 which should return Z. But it returns AA

Answer (score 0):

This will work up to 52.

```
Public Function ConvertToLetterA(ByRef iCol As Integer) As String

        Select Case iCol
            Case 1 To 26
                Return Chr(iCol + 64)

            Case 27 To 52
                Return "A" & Chr(iCol - 26 + 64)

        End Select

End Function
```

On a side note, you can write XLSX files directly with [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) via .Net.  You can use letter notation for columns if you wish, or you can use numbers.

Comment: Thanks. But I am looking for a more general rule of converting numbers to excel columns